# How to open a type file [suppose an image] for editing using our windows phone 8 application?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I created an `Image Processing` application through which we can `edit our images`. We can select Images for editing `from Phone Gallery or by using Camera` using my application.

I noticed that when we selecting an Image from the gallery and clicking `Edit application bar menu button` , it shows number of photo editing applications that we can choose to edit our Image. One example is  `Nokia Creative Studio` .

[image]

Since my application also `supports Image Editing` , I wanted to add My application to the list.   
How we can do that in Windows Phone 8 ? I didn't find anything on this topic.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at [Photo extensibility for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202966%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)